# hovering over a link

Tags: html

I have a question:
Is there any way to show the `ID` when you are hovering over a paragraph?
I made a fiddle to explain it.

[**Fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/9L2ns0nL).

Hope you guys know if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean Id from query string?

Comment: You have to try something, then if it doesn't work, you ask a question showing your code. Google "show id onmouseover"

Comment: yeah i mean id from query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after setting p contents when you hover over the link, then you'll use onmouseover. Get the p element and set the innerText/innerhtml in JavaScript

```
<a href="somepage.php?id=3" data-id="3" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ptag').innerHtml(this.getAttribute('data-id'))">hover</a>

<p id="ptag"></p>
```

However, this way doesn't parse the url of the link

```
<a href="somepage.php?id=3" data-id="3" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ptag').innerHtml(this.getAttribute('href'))">hover</a>

<p id="ptag"></p>
```

This will show the link to the user in the p tag.

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

This link will help you parse the url and get the id value from the link

Comment: Can you help me with that? I am not that experienced with js

Comment: Updated answer with some sample, not at a comp to test but the gist is there

Comment: Mark as answer if it helped, you may need to update the question to say hovering over a link

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS solution: you can use `:after` psudo element in combination with the `attr()` css function.

```css
#name_1 {  
  background-color: gold;  
}

#name_2 {
  background-color: skyblue;  
}

#name_1:hover::after {
  content: attr(id);
  position: absolute;  
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: lavender;
}

#name_2:hover::after {
  content: attr(id);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<p id=name_1>text text text text<br> text text text text </p>
<p id=name_2>text text text text<br> text text text text </p>
```

Comment: Nice solution but the OP needs to do some parsing of the attribute

Answer (score 1):

To get, the **ID** from the **query string**
and not the **id** of the element (http://jsfiddle.net/9L2ns0nL/5/),
you can use jquery `$(this).attr('href')` and then split the resulting string according to the url pattern.
see: http://jsfiddle.net/9L2ns0nL/9/

No confusing variables names next time.